# Inserting Records in Ascending Order function- C homework assignment

Tags: c, list, sorting

Good day, Stack Overflow.

I have a homework assignment that I'm working on this weekend that I'm having a bit of a problem with. We have a struct "Record" (which contains information about cars for a dealership) that gets placed in a particular spot in a linked list according to 1) its make and 2) according to its model year.

This is done when initially building the list, when a "int insertRecordInAscendingOrder" function is called in Main. In "insertRecordInAscendingOrder", a third function, "createRecord" is called, where the linked list is created. The function then goes to the function "compareCars" to determine what elements get put where. Depending on the value returned by this function, insertRecordInAscendingOrder then places the record where it belongs. The list is then printed out. There's more to the assignment, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Ideally, and for the assignment to be considered correct, the linked list must be ordered as:

```
    Chevrolet 2012 25
    Chevrolet 2013 10
    Ford 2010 5
    Ford 2011 3
    Ford 2012 15
    Honda 2011 9
    Honda 2012 3
    Honda 2013 12
    Toyota 2009 2
    Toyota 2011 7
    Toyota 2013 20
```

from the a text file that has the data ordered the following way:

```
    Ford 2012 15
    Ford 2011 3
    Ford 2010 5
    Toyota 2011 7
    Toyota 2012 20
    Toyota 2009 2
    Honda 2011 9
    Honda 2012 3
    Honda 2013 12
    Chevrolet 2013 10
    Chevrolet 2012 25
```

Notice that the alphabetical order of the "make" field takes precedence, then, the model year is arranged from oldest to newest.

However, the program produces this as the final list:

```
    Chevrolet 2012 25
    Chevrolet 2013 10
    Honda 2011 9
    Honda 2012 3
    Honda 2013 12
    Toyota 2009 2
    Toyota 2011 7
    Toyota 2012 20
    Ford 2010 5
    Ford 2011 3
    Ford 2012 15
```

I sat down with a grad student and tried to work out all of this yesterday, but we just couldn't figure out why it was kicking the Ford nodes down to the end of the list.

Here's the code. As you'll notice, I included a printList call at each instance of the insertion of a node. This way, you can see just what is happening when the nodes are being put in "order". It is in ANSI C99. All function calls *must* be made as they are specified, so unfortunately, there's no real way of getting around this problem by creating a more efficient algorithm.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 50
#define MAX_MAKE 20

typedef struct record
{
    char *make;
    int year;
    int stock;
    struct record *next;
} Record;

int compareCars(Record *car1, Record *car2);
void printList(Record *head);
Record* createRecord(char *make, int year, int stock);
int insertRecordInAscendingOrder(Record **head, char *make, int year, int stock);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *inFile = NULL;
    char line[MAX_LINE + 1];
    char *make, *yearStr, *stockStr;
    int year, stock, len;
    Record* headRecord = NULL;

    /*Input and file diagnostics*/
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf ("Filename not provided.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if((inFile=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    /*obtain values for linked list*/
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, inFile))
    {
        make = strtok(line, " ");
        yearStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        stockStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        year = atoi(yearStr);
        stock = atoi(stockStr);
        insertRecordInAscendingOrder(&headRecord,make, year, stock);

    }


    printf("The original list in ascending order: \n");
    printList(headRecord);
}

/*use strcmp to compare two makes*/

int compareCars(Record *car1, Record *car2)
{
    int compStrResult;
    compStrResult = strcmp(car1->make, car2->make);
    int compYearResult = 0;

    if(car1->year > car2->year)
    {
        compYearResult = 1;
    }
    else if(car1->year == car2->year)
    {
        compYearResult = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        compYearResult = -1;
    }

    if(compStrResult == 0 )
    {
        if(compYearResult == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(compYearResult == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return compStrResult;
        }
    }
    else if(compStrResult == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int insertRecordInAscendingOrder(Record **head, char *make, int year, int stock)
{
    Record *previous = *head;
    Record *newRecord = createRecord(make, year, stock);
    Record *current = *head;
    int compResult;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newRecord;
        printf("Head is null, list was empty\n");
        printList(*head);
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( compareCars(newRecord, *head)==-1) 
    {
        *head = newRecord;
        (*head)->next = current;
        printf("New record was less than the head, replacing\n");
        printList(*head);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("standard case, searching and inserting\n");
        previous = *head;

        while ( current != NULL &&(compareCars(newRecord, current)==1)) 
        {
            printList(*head);
            previous = current; 
            current = current->next; 
        }

        printList(*head);
        previous->next = newRecord;
        previous->next->next = current;
    }
    return 1;
}

/*creates records from info passed in from main via insertRecordInAscendingOrder.*/
Record* createRecord(char *make, int year, int stock)
{
    printf("CreateRecord\n");
    Record *theRecord;
    int len;

    if(!make)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    theRecord = malloc(sizeof(Record));

    if(!theRecord)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory for the structure.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    theRecord->year = year;
    theRecord->stock = stock;

    len = strlen(make);
    theRecord->make = malloc(len + 1);
    strncpy(theRecord->make, make, len);
    theRecord->make[len] = '\0';
    theRecord->next=NULL;

    return theRecord;
}

/*prints list. lists print.*/
void printList(Record *head)
{
    int i;
    int j = 50;
    Record *aRecord;
    aRecord = head;

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%20s%20s%10s\n", "Make", "Year", "Stock");

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");

    while(aRecord != NULL)
    {       
        printf("%20s%20d%10d\n", aRecord->make, aRecord->year,
        aRecord->stock);        
        aRecord = aRecord->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The text file you'll need for a command line argument can be saved under any name you like; here are the contents you'll need:

```
    Ford 2012 15
    Ford 2011 3
    Ford 2010 5
    Toyota 2011 7
    Toyota 2012 20
    Toyota 2009 2
    Honda 2011 9
    Honda 2012 3
    Honda 2013 12
    Chevrolet 2013 10
    Chevrolet 2012 25
```

Thanks in advance for your help. I shall continue to plow away at it myself.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848633/c-linked-list-errors/12849646#12849646) gives C code to insert an element into a single linked list, and it is pretty clean.

Comment: Well, the items are being inserted, it's just the order that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that

```
else if(compStrResult == 1)
```

you check against a specific return value of `strcmp`. The specification only says the result is positive, negative, or zero in the respective cases, and often it's the difference between the first differing characters. You should check

```
if (compStrResult > 0)
```

there.

Comment: For the time being, that works! 

I'll work on the code further and let you know if this holds true with the addition of more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a very simple testsuite will show you that the error is in compareCars.

Since the comparison of years is rather straight forward, look at the documentation for strcmp: It does not return 0, 1 or -1, but 0 or a positive or negative integer.

```
int compareCars(Record *car1, Record *car2)
{
    int makecmp = strcmp(car1->make, car2->make);

    if( makecmp > 0 )
      return 1;

    if( makecmp == 0 )
    {
        if (car1->year > car2->year)
          return 1;
        if( car1->year == car2->year )
          return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

An example testsuite for that function:

```
#include <assert.h>

void main()
{
  Record c1 = {"Toyota", 1991};
  Record c2 = {"Toyota", 1992};
  Record c3 = {"Ford", 1991};
  Record c4 = {"Ford", 1992};

  assert( compareCars( &c1, &c2 ) == -1 );
  assert( compareCars( &c1, &c1 ) == 0 );
  assert( compareCars( &c2, &c1 ) == 1 );
  assert( compareCars( &c2, &c3 ) == 1 );
  assert( compareCars( &c3, &c2 ) == -1 );
  assert( compareCars( &c3, &c4 ) == -1 );
  assert( compareCars( &c4, &c3 ) == 1 );
  assert( compareCars( &c4, &c1 ) == -1 );
}
```

Then, a note: in createRecord I recommend the use of `strdup` instead of malloc/strncpy and friends.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways: your code after fix; work on coding style

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 50
#define MAX_MAKE 20

typedef struct record
{
    char *make;
    int year;
    int stock;
    struct record *next;
} Record;

int compareCars(Record *car1, Record *car2);
void printList(Record *head);
Record* createRecord(char *make, int year, int stock);
int insertRecordInAscendingOrder(Record **head, char *make, int year, int stock);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *inFile = NULL;
    char line[MAX_LINE + 1];
    char *make, *yearStr, *stockStr;
    int year, stock, len;
    Record* headRecord = NULL;

    /*Input and file diagnostics*/
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf ("Filename not provided.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if((inFile=fopen(argv[1], "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open the file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    /*obtain values for linked list*/
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE, inFile))
    {
        make = strtok(line, " ");
        yearStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        stockStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        year = atoi(yearStr);
        stock = atoi(stockStr);

       // fprintf (stderr, "Record read Make[%s] Year[%d] Stock[%d]", make, year, stock);
        insertRecordInAscendingOrder(&headRecord,make, year, stock);

    }


    printf("The original list in ascending order: \n");
    printList(headRecord);

    scanf ("%d", &len);

    return 0;
}

/*use strcmp to compare two makes*/

int compareCars(Record *car1, Record *car2)
{
    int compStrResult;
    compStrResult = strcmp(car1->make, car2->make);
    int compYearResult = 0;

    if(car1->year > car2->year)
    {
        compYearResult = 1;
    }
    else if(car1->year == car2->year)
    {
        compYearResult = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        compYearResult = -1;
    }

    if(compStrResult == 0 )
    {
        if(compYearResult == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(compYearResult == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return compStrResult;
        }
    }
    else if(compStrResult > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

int insertRecordInAscendingOrder(Record **head, char *make, int year, int stock)
{
    Record *previous = *head;
    Record *newRecord = createRecord(make, year, stock);
    Record *current = *head;
    //int compResult;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newRecord;
        printf("Head is null, list was empty\n");
        //printList(*head);
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( compareCars(newRecord, *head)==-1)
    {
        *head = newRecord;
        (*head)->next = current;
        printf("New record was less than the head, replacing\n");
        //printList(*head);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("standard case, searching and inserting\n");
        previous = *head;

        while ( current != NULL &&(compareCars(newRecord, current)==1))
        {
            //printList(*head);
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        //printList(*head);
        previous->next = newRecord;
        previous->next->next = current;
    }
    return 1;
}

/*creates records from info passed in from main via insertRecordInAscendingOrder.*/
Record* createRecord(char *make, int year, int stock)
{
    printf("CreateRecord\n");
    Record *theRecord;
    int len;

    if(!make)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    theRecord = malloc(sizeof(Record));

    if(!theRecord)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory for the structure.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    theRecord->year = year;
    theRecord->stock = stock;

    len = strlen(make);
    theRecord->make = malloc(len + 1);
    strncpy(theRecord->make, make, len);
    theRecord->make[len] = '\0';
    theRecord->next=NULL;

    return theRecord;
}

/*prints list. lists print.*/
void printList(Record *head)
{
    int i;
    int j = 50;
    Record *aRecord;
    aRecord = head;

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%20s%20s%10s\n", "Make", "Year", "Stock");

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");

    while(aRecord != NULL)
    {
        printf("%20s%20d%10d\n", aRecord->make, aRecord->year,
        aRecord->stock);
        aRecord = aRecord->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```